# Talking about contextual things... Which Pronouns to use?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, words, pronouns

Apologies is this is an easy to answer or hard to explain question...
In English we often use demonstrative pronouns to reference what we just talked about.

For example:
The busiest stations in the world are in Japan.  Such as Shinjuku, Shibuya, or Umeda.  Everyday, millions of people use **these** stations.

Now I've always had issues with trying this in Japanese.
世界に一番忙しい駅は日本にあります。例えば、しんじゅく駅やしぶや駅やうめだ駅です。毎日、数百万の人は「**何々**」を使います。

Initially, I feel like I would just drop the は and just do 毎日、数百万の人が使います。Is this the only way to get the same meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most natural phrase choices there would include:

> 「これらの駅{えき}」 or 「これらの[3駅]{さんえき}」.

This might surprise you, but quite a few native speakers would aslo use:

> 「この3駅」

which is also a very natural phrase for us natve speakers.

What you would rarely see/hear us use in this particular context is just the pronoun 「これら」.

Finally, this has nothing to do with your question, but you need to say 「世界**で**一番」 instead of 「世界**に**一番」.

And it is 「数百万の人**が**」 and not 「数百万の人**は**」.

> Initially, I feel like I would just drop the は and just do 毎日、数百万の人が使います。Is this the only way to get the same meaning?

That is actually a good idea.  It would even be better if you used the emphatic 「もの」 instead of the plain 「の」 and said 「数百万人**もの**人（or 人々）」.

Comment: Thank You!  And sorry for the grammar errors in the example sentence.